# a bug or an error with inheritance and creating UTF-8 files

Tags: java, inheritance, utf-8, io, ansi

I have tested the best and more secure way to produce **UTF-8** text file, but when I'm using it in multiple **abstract classes**, it produce **ANSI format** files not UTF-8 format!
Is there any bug or something to preventing it?
Again, my code is correct and when I put all code in a single class, program could create **UTF-8** files without any problem.

I provide you code by 3 class files which is necessary for test:

class A0.java:

```
public class A0 extends A1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // if you want to use A1 which is extended by this class
    // uncomment this two lines
    // A1 run = new A1();
    // run.save();
    // But if you want to use A2 which isn't extended or inherited
    // uncomment this lines
    // A2 a2 = new A2();
    // try {
    // a2.create_new_file("c:/test.txt");
    // a2.append_line_to_file("برنامه نویسی");
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    // }
    // Question: Why in A1 we cannot produce properly UTF-8 text file?
 }
}
```

class A1.java:

```
public class A1 extends A2{
protected void save() {
    A2 a2 = new A2();
    try {
        a2.create_new_file("c:/test.txt");
        a2.append_line_to_file("برنامه نویسی");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 }
}
```

class A2.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class A2 {
private BufferedWriter writer;

public void create_new_file(String file_address) throws Exception {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_address, true));
    Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file_address), Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_address, true));
}

public void append_line_to_file(String line) throws IOException {
    try {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: The code clearly isn't correct if it isn't producing the right output. But without actually showing it it's impossible for others to know what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You have provided no specific information, making it impossible for anyone to help you.  As it stands, this question is off-topic and will likely be closed quickly.  Also, be very careful when stating that there is a bug in the Java system.  While many bugs do exist, 99% of the time the problem is misunderstanding on the user's part.

Comment: This is a technical problem, but I try to provide a code for it as soon as possible.

Comment: Now it's ready and you could see what I asked in code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **wasn't** a bug or an error for Java. It was **my fault** to encode source file as **UTF-8**.
So, if you're using Eclipse IDE:
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".
other IDE should have similar way.